# Тенденции в использовании стандартов безопасности WiFi WPA2 и WPA3

Tags: wifi

Каково текущее соотношение между роутерами, работающими на стандартах безопасности WiFi WPA2 и WPA3? Есть ли какие-либо доверенные источники, где можно узнать, сколько роутеров используют WPA 2, а сколько WPA 3?